# How do you draw to the view using Core Graphics on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, core-graphics

I'm new to iPhone programming and can't figure out how to use Core Graphics. The code I am testing with is:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextClearRect(ctx, rect);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 255, 255, 0, 1);
CGContextStrokeRect(ctx, CGRectMake(195, 195, 60, 60)); }
```

I put it in the ViewController.m file on a default View based application but nothing happens when the application is run.

Comment: What do you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`drawRect` is a method of the `UIView` class, not `UIViewController`. You need to create your own `UIView` subclass and implement that one’s `drawRect`. To actually use the class, just set the class name in the `xib` file that comes with the view.

Comment: Unless you created the view yourself.

Comment: I assumed “default View based application” meant one created from an Xcode template which should include the xib.

Answer (score 0):

There are more resource available to learn [Core Graphics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreGraphics/Reference/CoreGraphics_Framework/_index.html), you just need to google ..

See some good link to know more about Core Graphics and its uses.

[Getting Started with Graphics & Animation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_GraphicsImaging/_index.html)

[Core Graphics 101: Patterns](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2167/core-graphics-101-patterns)